# Could not complete this programme

Tags: java

I'm new to programming so I'm not able to complete this programme.
I'm required to create a fast food eatery that asks the customer's name, their choice, quantity, phone number, and whether they would like to order something else.
I'm managed to take the inputs from the customer but the only problem is that I can't I can't figure out to add the subtotal if the customers chooses to order something else. Like if they had the total of $10 and make an order of another $10, how am I supposed to add the total and display the bill?
I apologize if I'm not able to explain myself.
Here's what I've done till now:

```
import java.util.*;
public class KFC 
{
    public void display_menu() 
    {
        System.out.println("**********WELCOME TO XYZ**********");
        System.out.println("MAY I KNOW WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE?");
        System.out.println("1.OMG Burger:-");
        System.out.println("2.OMG Roller:-");
        System.out.println("3.Chicken Snacker:-");
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice");
    }

    public void question()
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to have something else?");
        System.out.println("To place another order enter 9.");
        System.out.println("To check out enter 0.");
        Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);  

        switch (q.nextInt()) 
        {
        case 0:
            break;

        case 9:System.out.println ("Please proceed.");
        new KFC();
        break;
        default:System.out.println ( " option" );
        break;
        }
    }


    public KFC() 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        display_menu();

        switch (sc.nextInt()) 
        {
        case 1:int a,b,Rate;String s;
        double e,t,f,g;
        float m;
        System.out.println("OMG Burger");
        System.out.println("Enter The Quantity");
        b=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name");
        s=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Mobile Number");
        m=sc.nextFloat();
        Rate=49;
        t=(5.0/100.0)*Rate;
        e=b*Rate;
        f=t*b;
        g=e+f;
        question();
        System.out.println("***********KFC**********");
        System.out.println("Name:"+s);
        System.out.println("Mobile Number:"+m);
        System.out.println("Choice:OMG Burger");
        System.out.println("Quantity:"+b);
        System.out.println("Rate:$"+Rate);
        System.out.println("Tax:"+f);
        System.out.println("Total price:$"+g);
        System.out.println("PLEASE VISIT AGAIN. HAVE A NICE DAY!!!");
        break;
        case 2:  System.out.println("OMG Roller");
        System.out.println("Enter The Quantity");
        b=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name");
        s=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Mobile Number");
        m=sc.nextFloat();
        Rate=59;
        t=(5.0/100.0)*Rate;
        e=b*Rate;
        f=t*b;
        g=e+f;
        question();
        System.out.println("***********KFC**********");
        System.out.println("Name:"+s);
        System.out.println("Mobile Number:"+m);
        System.out.println("Choice:OMG Roller");
        System.out.println("Quantity:"+b);
        System.out.println("Rate:$"+Rate);
        System.out.println("Tax:"+f);
        System.out.println("Total price:$"+g);
        System.out.println("PLEASE VISIT AGAIN. HAVE A NICE DAY!!!");
        break;
        case 3:   System.out.println("Chicken Snacker");
        System.out.println("Enter The Quantity");
        b=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name"); 
        s=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Your Mobile Number");
        m=sc.nextFloat();
        Rate=40;
        t=(5.0/100.0)*Rate;
        e=b*Rate;
        f=t*b;
        g=e+f;
        question();
        System.out.println("***********KFC**********");
        System.out.println("Name:"+s);
        System.out.println("Mobile Number:"+m);
        System.out.println("Choice:Chicken Snacker");
        System.out.println("Quantity:"+b);
        System.out.println("Rate:$"+Rate);
        System.out.println("Tax:"+f);
        System.out.println("Total price:$"+g);
        System.out.println("PLEASE VISIT AGAIN. HAVE A NICE DAY!!!");
        break;
        default:
            System.out.println ( "Unrecognized option" );
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        new KFC();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a bad practise that you print all details of a customer in each case use your cases to calculate the money for different items and make a global variable for adding money , In your case you are limiting your each item cost , that's why u didnt get proper result

Comment: Oh god. So let's start by 1/ naming your variable with meaningful names (no more a, b, c etc) 2/ use proper case (a variable name starts with a lowercase letter) 3/ correct indentation. When this is done, post your updated code. Regarding you problem, what do you think `new KFC()` does?

Answer (score 1):

Initially you are creating new instance of KFC for the a new customer....now **when same customer place another order again you create new instance of KFC rather using same instance..bcoz you have placed your logic inside constructor which is totally wrong.** As pointed out by oguzhand this will not help in totalling

**Constructors are used to initialize the instances of your classes.** Often it is used to create new objects often with parameters specifying the initial state or other important information about the object

From the official Java tutorial:

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from
>   the class blueprint.
>   For more info on constructors [refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

**1)So instead of writing your logic inside constructor....write it in a method and call that method**. 
 
**2)Also as pointed out by RC and oguzhand you should give meaningful names to variable and should use few global variable. For Example**

```
String customerName; 
long customerContactNo; 
long totalPrice; 
int burgerQuantity; 
int rollerQuantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Points already made by others:
1) Name your variables using some meaningful name
2) Don't do your work in the constructor

It seems as though you're trying to write *a program* to solve your problem rather than to write *a set of classes*. When working in Java, you ought to be creating an object oriented solution to the problem.

Ask yourself first about how many of something you have. For each order, how many customers? How many menu items in an order? Since a single customer can order more than one menu item, you should have a class for menu items ordered in a single order.

So far I'm seeing at least three different classes to be written:
1) A class to represent a working day at your restaurant;
2) A class to represent an order; and
3) A class to represent an item in the order.

To get the subtotal for the order, you can just iterate over the OrderItem objects, ask each one how much it costs, and add that to a variable. Store the value in a field on the Order class (or recalculate and return it whenever it's needed) and you're good to go.